# Bitrix24 CRM menu Label text changes

Tags: bitrix

I have self hosted bitrix24 and would like to change CRM header as below. Deals -> Projects , Companies - > Deals, Contacts -> Companies. Please if someone done it need helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you should not rename interface items in such way because it  will confuse users! It's not just names, they imply a business logic.

But if you still want to change menu settings in Bitrix (i.e. menu items order) use following instructions:

1. Login as admin user.
2. Turn on edit mode as [image: Screenshot 1]
3. Place mouse cursor on top of main menu. Wait a half a second for floating settings pane and then select "Edit menu" button: [image]
4. In opened Edit menu dialog you can change titles and links of menu items, change their order and even delete: [image]

p.s. Sorry for russian l10n in screenshots, but hope they help.